# component styleUrls not working in production build Angular

Tags: angular

I recently updated one of my projects to Angular 13 from 10, during development everything worked just fine. Then when I generated a production build to notice that there were styling issues. After some investigation, I find out that the problem has to do with `styleUrls` somehow not reading the stylesheet link. I found [this post](https://quizdeveloper.com/faq/css-component-not-working-when-defined-styleurls-in-angular-aid74) and [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8577), and more like them providing some workaround, not solutions and specifics on why that's happening. I only tried one of the suggested fixes because most did not look like viable solutions.

I tried the `require` method; replacing `styleUrls` with `styles` then requiring the stylesheet like so `require('home.component.css')` it works however my styling is in `scss` and my project is quite large it will take me forever to update all the `styleUrls` to `styles`.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening exactly and what the fix is?

There are no issues in the development server, only when the final build is generated

Sample code, not much changed from the update (Angular 10 -> 13) I can't think of any other code to provide to help.

*home.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'], // <-- problematic
  // styles: [require('home.component.css')] // works, notice the ext change I have css file to go along

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  //...
  constructor(/** ... */) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

*home.component.html*

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

*home.component.scss*

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    /* ... */
}
```

In development `ng serve`, I can see the red background

In production `ng build` or `ng build --configuration production --aot` I can't see it, it defaults to white

Comment: Please also add the respective code parts to your questions, otherwise we don't have any chance to answer your question properly.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question with the relevant code. The issue affects the whole project all the `styleUrls` are behaving that way. I just included a sample code

Answer (score 1):

I left this project alone until a few days ago when I got a hint of a solution while working on a different project. Going from Angular [10](https://devdocs.io/angular%7E10/guide/workspace-config) to [13](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config) the Angular workspace configuration, `angular.json`, changed a bit (since [v11](https://devdocs.io/angular%7E11/guide/workspace-config) actually) and that's where it got me. I had the nested property [`optimization`](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration) (see v10 codes below) set to `true` under the `production` environment and `false` under `development`. when set to `true` It performs a bunch of optimization on scripts & styles and since v11 on fonts too. `styles` on v10 was just a boolean property that, when set to `true`, minified the styles. Since v11, `styles` can also be an object with boolean properties `minify` & `inlineCritical`. By default, they are set to `true`. In my case, the issue was with [`inlineCritical`](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options) so I set it to `false` (see v13 codes below).

This is not a solid solution, since an optimization option meant to "boost" performance is being turned off. I will keep investigating why exactly this is happening and posts any updates.

Simplified `angular.json` v10

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "app_name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true // <=== The issue 
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simplified `angular.json` v13

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "app_name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": {
                "styles": {
                  "inlineCritical": false // <=== The fix
                }
              }
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Additional context; this project is using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for styling and the other one that gave me a hint is using [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/); I had the same issue with both.